Extracting data from a web map
I'm still very new to the chrome developer tool so I am completely lost knowing where to look to extract spatial data.  I was wanting to pull the flood risk areas for Spain from here
and load it into ArcGIS Pro to compare to a flood risk analysis I've made.

500 Year Flood Plain is WMS (Raster png) format from https://servicios.idee.es/wms-inspire/riesgos-naturales/inundaciones?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&STYLES=&VERSION=1.3.0&WMTVER=1.3.0&LAYERS=NZ.Flood.FluvialT500&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A25830&BBOX=721111.6840233635%2C4350822.038777415%2C729578.3676233974%2C4359288.722377448
